# ACF field to create sets of pages when saved

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an odd request, i'm not sure if this is even possible. But i'll try to work out the process below, and if anyone can help me work this out that would be amazing!

Ideally the process is as follows:

1. Admin goes to parent options page, within the options page there is a repeater field, called add new company. This will just be a field with a title.
2. Admin fills in field and presses save. This will generate a sub options page with that name, within the options field, there will be a set of fields like logo, a colour picker and some text fields (these could be a set of fields from within ACF if thats possible).
3. Also when this original Repeater Field is made/saved a set of pages is generated from a set of templates. Essentially using the name from the repeater field to be the main page title for the top level page and all the sub pages below are just dynamically generated. They don't need to have anything different about them, they just need to generate from a set of page templates. It needs to be able to associate with the newly generated company bits from the sub options field.

This will then essentially give the admin a new set of pages which will use the new options logo / colours etc. It would almost need to generate a new set of templates based off the master templates to dynamically make sure it picked up the correct information from the sub options page.

I'm not sure if this is possible, I have seen it work elsewhere on another job I have worked on (not exactly the same as the above but similar), but I can't work out the process to make it work sadly, as I have a horrid feeling that there is some complex bits within the database going on to do the duplication dynamically.

My other option is to run everything as a WordPress Multisite but I was trying to avoid that if possible on this occasion, but I may have to use Multisite to achieve the above.

If anyone can help me work this out that would be amazing!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to plug into the `save_post` action and create new subpages from there.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'create_sub_pages' ); //Plug into save_post action

//Function create sub_pages
function create_sub_pages($post_ID) {

    //Repeater field name
    $repeater_field_array = get_field('repeater_field_name');

    //Loops through all of the items in the repeater field
    foreach($repeater_field_array as $key => $value) {

        //Check to see if there is already a sub page with that post name
        $child_pages = get_pages(array( 'child_of' => $post_ID ));
        $child_page_exists = false;

        foreach($child_pages as $pages) {
            if ($pages->post_title === $key) {
                    $child_page_exists = true;
            }
        }

        //If not, set up the creation of the new post
        if ($child_page_exists === false) {
            $new_page_title = esc_html__( $key );
            $new_page_content = ''; 
            $new_page = array(
                'post_type'      => 'page',
                'post_date'      => esc_attr( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) ),
                'post_date_gmt'  => esc_attr( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) ),
                'post_title'     => esc_attr( $new_page_title ),
                'post_name'      => sanitize_title( $new_page_title ), //This could from the sub_field in the repeater
                'post_content'   => $new_page_content,
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_parent'    => $post_ID,
                'menu_order'     => $new_page_order
            );
            $new_page_id = wp_insert_post( $new_page );
            update_post_meta( $new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $value );
        }

    }

}
```

Again, this is just a spitball since there was not much code to review, but it could help you get going in the right direction.

Comment: @ChrisMitchell did this get you going in the right direction?